# Data truncation from FTP download using Apache

Tags: java, apache, file, ftp, ftp-client

Using the Apache FTP client from `commons-net:commons-net:3.6`, I'm reading files from our FTPS server with

```
FTPClient#retrieveFile("/OUT/somefile.xml", someBAOS)
```

Normally, everything works well, but sometimes the file gets truncated.

This is the protocol when everything works:

```
< 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (someserver) [::ffff:...]
> AUTH TLS
< 234 AUTH TLS successful
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ 0 successful
> PROT P
< 200 Protection set to Private
> USER someuser
< 331 Password required for someuser
> PASS ***
< 230 User someuser logged in
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (...).
> RETR /OUT/somefile.xml
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /OUT/somefile.xml (4769503 bytes)
< 226 Transfer complete
```

When the file got truncated, the smaller size was logged:

```
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /OUT/somefile.xml (2569402 bytes)
```

The truncation happens sporadically. On the next download, one hour later, everything is fine again. We're pretty sure that the file hasn't changed during this period.

The log file was produced using `SocketClient#addProtocolCommandListener` and I'm pretty sure that the changed size doesn't come from my listener. I guess, the text was produced by the FTP server and dumped as is. *Can someone confirm that the file size indeed comes from the server (rather than being added by the Apache client)?*

Funnily, the downloaded truncated file has 2602133 bytes (and I'm rather sure, there are no `\r`s added by text conversion or alike; Firstly, we do conversion; secondly, the difference is 31371 bytes and there are 56577 lines there).

The most probable explanation would be someone changing the file in the meantime, but the server logs clearly say that there was nobody else at the time.

*Any idea how to find out what's going on?*

## The result

I've got some more logs showing clearly that there were uploads *around* the time of the problem. At the same time, the logs claim, that there was no timing overlap. Anyway, with the confirmation that the `150 ...` line comes directly from the server, there's no doubt that the concurrent access was the culprit.

Comment: Missing bytes or truncated? I assume truncated but worth confirming. Know of a few similar sounding bugs but think most addressed by 3.3

Comment: You seem to have two separate issues.  Note the `<` indicating it's a message received from the server, so the _server_ thinks the file is smaller...  As to the discrepancy between the server's idea of the size and the actual received size, we'd have to see the code, to see what happens to `someBAOS`.

Comment: Encoding? Maybe `ftpClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");` (I know its binary mode and shouldn't matter).

Comment: @ficuscr Truncated, nothing missing before, just checked. Concerning encoding: No filenames contains any special chars. There are no files to be confused with. But yes, I'll `setControlEncoding`.

Comment: @JimGarrison The `<` comes from me, but yes, it's called from `protocolReplyReceived` (there's no processing on my side, other the filtering the PWD). I could imagine the Apache extending the message (which would be damn stupid, but stupid stuff happens all the time). Concerning the code, there's nothing anybody could mess up in `someBAOS.toByteArray()` and logging the length on the next line. Anyway, I've checked it dozens of times... and the download works pretty much always with some rare exception - IMHO such a bug must be network-related.

Comment: Honestly grasping at straws... encoding, mod_defalte (gzip) are the things that jump into mind. That said, fair number of bug reports related to that lib and retrieving files of certain sizes. Looking at some old code and we used retrieveFileStream I think maybe because of some issue we encountered.

Comment: @ficuscr: `setControlEncoding` only affects the control connection and not the data connection - and thus will not affect the file size. FTP servers don't change the file anyway except the line ending in ASCII mode - but here binary mode is used. gzip or anything similar is also not used in FTP since there is no way to signal to the peer that the data are transferred compressed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Even in ASCII mode I have doubts that the server will report a different number of bytes in the 150-message. This message is sent out as soon as the data socket is opened while the ASCII-conversion takes place during transfer. In order to report the correct size at that point of time, the server would need to parse through the whole file which might mean gigabytes of data, just to report a number that is not required by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message

```
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /OUT/somefile.xml (2569402 bytes)
```

is coming from the server, i.e. the server that is serving the file only sees a files with a length of 2569402 bytes. The most likely reason - without knowing the actual systems involved here - is that the file you try to download is currently been created. That's why it's working a couple of minutes later because the file creation is finished then.

This is a common problem with different solutions out there:

- The creation of a lock-file of the same name with a defined prefix or suffix that you can check for existence and only perform the download if it's not existent.
- Checking the size for some time and only attempt a download if the size doesn't change for a while.
- Create the file with a temporary name or into a different directory and rename/move it to the target name and destination

As I said, I don't think that it's a problem with your client, the server clearly reports the wrong length so the reason for the problem must be there.

Answer (score 2):

A `150 Opening...` message is  send by the server immediately after the data connection is established, i.e. when the data transfer starts. This means that message contains the size of the file from the perspective of the server when the data transfer starts. This means that the file is not truncated during transfer but instead was smaller then you've expected on the server side already.

Since binary mode is used no changing of the line ending is done at the server side. Given that the actual download size you get is larger than the server has reported but smaller than you've expected it is likely that there is something changing the file at the server side while the download is running.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer as it was a tiny bit faster. I guess, you don't care.